# How to set FontFamily globally for all controls in the project with text property in Xamarin.Form app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a Xamarin.Form app for Android and iOS, and some users replace system default font with their own fonts, and FontSize property in Xaml doesn't work with these fonts, and these fonts are not so readable in my App. 1. So can I force the font used in my App to be system default font even the user changed font in their system config page?
2. If I can't do the above, can I set the FontFamily of all controls in my App with a text property to the font I included in my Android and iOS assets folder globally once and for all?
I've searched for some global font solution, but found no Xamarin.Form solution, and some solution seems to have been outdated.

For now, I set the FontFamily for controls one by one like this:

```
<Button FontFamily="{OnPlatform Android=xiaozuan.ttf#xiaozuan}"/>
```

There are so many controls that I can't really do this one by one...
Any clue or help would be appreicated!

Comment: To Clarify what to do (due to downvotes on the only answer): Define `Styles` in App.xaml. You'll still have to do this once per `type of control`, but that is much more convenient than putting that property in every individual control. But see my comment on that answer: you'll likely want to create TWO styles per type of control: one with a "key" name, one without a key. See X-Forms Styles doc for more info.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. So can I force the font used in my App to be system default font even the user changed font in their system config page?

If you want to change default fontfamily, I think you can override  default font using custom font.
https://www.infragistics.com/help/xamarin/overriding-default-font

> If I can't do the above, can I set the FontFamily of all controls in my App with a text property to the font I included in my Android and iOS assets folder globally once and for all

You can use [Global Styles in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/application) to change all element in your project, here is changing the font of all label.

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="sans-serif" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: About using global styles, Labels are not the only controls which fonts can be used on, other ones are Buttons, Entries, Editors, Pickers, etc. I don't know if could target a super class to apply for all of them, I only could find `IFontFamily` common interface, but that can't be set in TargetType.

Comment: @Vahid,If you want to use font for all controls, like Button, label, Entry..., you see the first link I provide, try to override default using custom font.https://www.infragistics.com/help/xamarin/overriding-default-font

Comment: Voted down because this answer does not offer a solution to the original question without a third party library and does not describe if it can be done with native code or not.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT - the infragistics link ONLY applies to controls from that vendor.

Comment: @VahidShir - Unfortunately, there is no base class on which FontFamily can be set. It is necessary to create a style for each type of control that uses text. Even more frustratingly, if you then create a different style for that control on a page, you have to remember to add the fontfamily to that page's style. OR you have to create a "keyed" style in App.xaml, and have each page's style "BasedOn" that. Which would be acceptable, but a "keyed" style won't apply automatically to any controls. So you'll also need a duplicate (but not-keyed) style in App.xaml, to apply when no style specified.